# High Voltage Serial-to-Parallel Over Many Channels

Tags: high-voltage, parallel, hvdc

I've been using the [HV507](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/hv507.pdf) for parallelization of a 300VDC supply, but the chip only has 64 channels. I was wondering how to drive this voltage to a much higher number of channels (say, 1,000).

Is this just a question of tracking down the highest-channel alternative to the HV507, and using as many in conjunction as necessary, or is there some special circuit I should employ for parallelizing a high DC voltage to an arbitrarily large number of channels? Is a custom IC necessary?

I'm very new to electronics and thus also to multiplexers and shift registers.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "parallelization" in this context?

Comment: @IanBland basically, replicate the behavior of the HV507 over many more channels: supply a high DC voltage and have it replicated on many separate channels

Comment: As in a buffer?

Comment: So are you actually transmitting data on these channels, or what? You're not describing what the channels do, just that you're "replicating" a DC voltage. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @IanBland my bad. No data—the channels route to pads. I want to be able to switch individual pads "on and off" of 300VDC

Comment: So I think you're looking at multiple chips and using a demultiplexed counter to enable each chip in turn using the Chip Select lines. If your counting is fairly complicated you could use a microcontroller with sufficient output pins to connect one to each chip.